# Detect cycles in graph, an implementation

Tags: scala, data-structures, graph

*t* is my first try to understand how to detect cycles in a graph. I tried to implement this pseudo-code for detecting cycles in a graph (directed or undirected):

```
 boolean containsCycle(Graph g):
     for each vertex v in g do:
       v.mark = WHITE;
     od;
     for each vertex v in g do:
       if v.mark == WHITE then:
        if visit(g, v) then:
          return TRUE;
        fi;
       fi;
     od;
    return FALSE;

   boolean visit(Graph g, Vertex v):
    v.mark = GREY;
    for each edge (v, u) in g do:
       if u.mark == GREY then:
         return TRUE;
       else if u.mark == WHITE then:
         if visit(g, u) then:
            return TRUE;
         fi;
       fi;
     od;
    v.mark = BLACK;
    return FALSE;
```

And here is my code in Scala:

```
def containsCycle(g: Graph): Boolean = {
    for (v <- g.vertices) v.mark = "WHITE"
    for (v <- g.vertices) {
      if (v.mark == "WHITE") {
        if (visit(g, v))
          return true
      }
    }
    return false
  }

  def visit(g: Graph, v: Vertex): Boolean = {
    v.mark = "GREY"
    for (e <- g.edges) {
      if (e.destination.mark == "GREY"){
        return true
      }
      else {

        if (e.destination.mark == "WHITE") {
          if (visit(g, e.destination))
            return true
        }
      }
    }
    v.mark = "BLACK"
    return false
  }
```

I do not know what I have coded wrong?

Comment: In `visit`, shouldn't `for (e <- g.edges)` be `for (e <- v.edges)` ? If you always iterates on the same edges, you will quickly find `GREY` vertices (cycles or not).

Comment: @DavidDuponchel , the first mistake is that I am using `return` expression and my program was terminating in the first edge that it was exterminating. :( 
I am using a matrix to represent edges, so I will try now to iterate though the neighbors of each edge, as you suggest. Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better match for the stackexchange code review site?

Comment: It would help if you gave some clue about what wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I have also used the coloring method for classifying nodes as unexplored(W), exploring(G) and Finished(B) exploring

Here is my code for detecting CYCLES in a graph(Connected and Disconnected). It is not super efficient but it gives the correct DFS output as well as indicates whether there is a cycle in the graph or not.

For detecting cycle you must take into account two conditions:

1. Selfloops

   or
2. We try to explore a vertex which is already in recursion stack(Grey Color)/ (Back Edge)

For the Second Condition, I have used Recursion Stack(Recur Stack).

I have used the idea given here [Algo for DFS(TH Cormen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSIko.jpg)
Follow this example [Example for the above Algo(TH Cormen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuZzS.png)

Although I have used the coloring method to understand DFS, I have not added the time feature given in the algo.

I hope the below code answer your question.

```
import collections

class Vertex:
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.color="W"

class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.master_vertex={}                                                                        
        self.Q=[]                                                                                    
        self.visit=[]                                                                                
        self.adj_vertex=collections.defaultdict(list)                                                
        self.cycle=0                                                                                 

    def add_vertex(self,vert):
        nv=Vertex(vert)
        self.master_vertex[vert]=nv

    def add_edge(self,src,dest):                                                                     
        self.adj_vertex[src].append(dest)



def DFS_Visit(graph):
        for ver in list(graph.master_vertex.keys()):
            if ver not in graph.visit and graph.master_vertex[ver].color=="W":
            DFS_iterative(graph,ver)
        if graph.cycle==1:
            return True
        else:
            return False


def DFS_iterative(graph,start):
    recur_stack=[]                                                                                      
    graph.Q.append(start)

    while len(graph.Q)>0:
        start=graph.Q[len(graph.Q)-1]                                                               
        recur_stack.append((graph.Q.pop()))
        graph.master_vertex[start].color="G"  

        if len(graph.adj_vertex[start])==0:                                                         
            graph.master_vertex[start].color="B"   
        for ver in graph.adj_vertex[start]:
            if start==ver or (graph.master_vertex[ver].color=="G" and ver in recur_stack):          
                graph.cycle=1
            if graph.master_vertex[ver].color=="W" and ver not in graph.Q:
                graph.Q.append(ver)
        graph.visit.append(start)

    while len(recur_stack)>0:
        x=recur_stack.pop()
        if graph.master_vertex[x].color=="G":
            graph.master_vertex[x].color="B"   


if __name__=='__main__':

    g=Graph()
    for i in range(1,7):
        g.add_vertex(str(input()))

    g.add_edge('u','v')
    g.add_edge('u','x')
    g.add_edge('v','y')
    g.add_edge('y','x')
    g.add_edge('x','v')
    g.add_edge('w','y')
    g.add_edge('w','z')
    g.add_edge('z','z')
    print g.adj_vertex
    print "Iterative DFS: "
    if DFS_Visit(g):
        print "graph contains cycle"
    else:
        print "graph does not contain cycle"
    print g.visit
```

OUTPUT FOR THE ABOVE CODE:
[CODE OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNQpa.png)